# CiviVolunteer jobs in drupal views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, civivolunteer, civicrm-entity

Is there a way to use the CiviVolunteer job opportunities in Drupal views?
If not would this need work on the CiviVolunteer extension or the CiviCRM entities module?

We are looking for a way to expose the vacancies in a nice and flexible way in our drupal views.

Answer (score 2):

Presently CiviVolunteer does not have a direct integration with Drupal Views. I have worked with the CiviCRM/Views integration before, but it's been quite a while now, so I'm not sure what's changed... that said, my work was integrating CiviCRM core fields with Drupal Views. I'm not sure what it would take -- or even if it would be all that different -- to integrate Drupal Views with entities defined by a CiviCRM extension.

As of version 2.0, CiviVolunteer does provide a filterable list of available volunteer opportunities. Here's [an example](http://civivolunteer.ginkgostreet.com/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities). Perhaps this obviates the need for a Views integration?